# Need to populate a column based on another column in another table

Tags: sql-server

I'm probably overthinking this so here goes.

I have two tables. The first one I want to populate the CorporationId based off it's TokenId value.

dbo.UsersAccountLink:

[image]

And the table that I want to get the value from:

Company.Token:

[image]

Here is what I have but it's not set right so it will not run. I'm not sure how to do this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.UsersAccountLink.CorporationId
Select CorporationId 
From Company.Token
Where Company.Token.TokenId = dbo.UsersAccountLink.TokenId
```

I want to populate dbo.UsersAccountLink.CorporationId with the value in Company.Token.CorporationId based on the TokenId.

Help?!

Comment: Be careful here. It looks like you likely are using uniqueidentifiers as your primary keys all over the place. This can cause incredibly poor performance if those primary keys are also the clustered index. Fragmentation of guids will exceed 99.99% with as few a thousand rows. You either need a better clustering column or you have to constantly defragment your indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want to update versus insert...

```
update dbo.UsersAccountLink
set CorporationID = 
(Select CorporationId 
From Company.Token
Where Company.Token.TokenId = dbo.UsersAccountLink.TokenId)
```

Comment: No sweat @ErocM and Roll Tide